# How to rollback, reset, or drop Ecto test database?

Tags: testing, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Usually `mix.test` cleans the test database, but it is not working.

It may be because I was playing around with making a `users` schema, but didn't want to use what I made so I got rid of it. I then started over and made a new schema for users which was different from the first.

When I tried to run mix test again, there was an error that some fields did not exist which should have been there with the new schema.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can access the test database by using `MIX_ENV=test` followed by a command such as `mix do ecto.drop`, `mix ecto.reset` or `mix ecto.rollback`.

In this particular case, I used:

```
MIX_ENV=test mix ecto.reset
```

---

If your application has multiple repos (DBs), you'll want to specify a specific repo to avoid applying the operation to all repos. For example

```
mix ecto.drop --repo Order.Repo
```

To find out more about an Ecto task, use `mix help <task>`

Answer (score 7):

You can set aliases into mix.exs like this

```
defp aliases do
  [
   "ecto.setup": ["ecto.create", "ecto.migrate", "run priv/repo/seeds.exs"],
   "ecto.reset": ["ecto.drop", "ecto.setup"],
   "test":       ["ecto.create --quiet", "ecto.migrate", "test"]
  ]
end
```

And you need to run database into sandbox mode.

Your /appdir/test/test_helper.exs should be like this

```
Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.mode(ProjectName.DB.Repo, {:shared, self()})
ExUnit.start(exclude: [:pending])
```

And /appdir/config/test.exs like this

```
config :project_name, ProjectName.DB.Repo,
  pool: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox,
  database: "database_name_test"
```

Comment: I had this setup but it doesn't really fix the problem at hand. It arises in situations such as 1) create migration 2) run `mix test` 3) change the migration 4) run `mix test` again. Since the migration has already run, mix won't see it as a new one and you can get errors such as a non-existent column. That being said, the aliases you described can be used to help fix this, like by using `MIX_ENV=test mix ecto.reset`.